# Unsupported Content-type:application/json in java webservice call

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jax-rs, jax-ws

I am able to set content type using cxf library but I don't know how to set Authorization header. Whenever I set user name and password then it set Authorization header and encode whole value and add Basic. I don't want to do this. I want to add Authorization header with plain string which ever I provide. Please help me to solve out this problem.

```
AMPServices services = new AMPServices();
        CoreXmlPort coreXmlPort = services.getAMPSoapService();
        Client client = ClientProxy.getClient(coreXmlPort);           

        HTTPConduit httpConduit = (HTTPConduit) client.getConduit();

        HTTPClientPolicy httpClientPolicy=httpConduit.getClient();
        String contentType=httpClientPolicy.getContentType();
        contentType="application/soap+xml; type=vnd.iShip.AMP.SOAP; charset=UTF-8";
        httpClientPolicy.setContentType(contentType);

        AuthorizationPolicy authorizationPolicy = new AuthorizationPolicy();
        authorizationPolicy.setUserName("username");
        authorizationPolicy.setPassword("password");

        httpConduit.setAuthorization(authorizationPolicy);
```

It generates following request xml.

```
POST https://api.iship.com/Root/Enterprises/Pitney%20Bowes/Progistics; HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: application/soap+xml; type=vnd.iShip.AMP.SOAP; charset=UTF-8
Accept: */*
Authorization: Basic aXNoaXAgcGIvd3NkZXZlbDowNzZhNjFjYTM5MDcxODAxODVjNWRkMjM2YTdkMzZhNGQ1ODg5OWFj
User-Agent: Apache CXF 3.1.0
Cache-Control: no-cache
Pragma: no-cache
Host: api.iship.com
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 246
```

But I want this type of request

```
POST https://api.iship.com/Root/Enterprises/Pitney%20Bowes/Progistics; HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: application/soap+xml; type=vnd.iShip.AMP.SOAP; charset=UTF-8
Accept: */*
Authorization: username;password
User-Agent: Apache CXF 3.1.0
Cache-Control: no-cache
Pragma: no-cache
Host: api.iship.com
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 246
```

But I was not able to do it. Please help me to solve out this problem.

Thanks,
Awadhendra

Comment: please highlight ConnectShipSoap.com.App.main(App.java:22) in your code

Comment: I had updated some information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are trying to call is a RestFul Service, so that's why the server side always response with a different content type than you expected (json instead of soap/xml). Is your url endpoint based on http protocol? If yes, do you need send additional parameters to this url?

Comment: I am able to consume same web service using .net client but not through java client.

Comment: That's weird, like Akash Yadav said, it looks like the server side is returning a JSON instead of an XML, so when you're trying to get the response using your third party libraries internally is trying to read any data with xml content type that's the problem. Let's try a different approach. Try to make a Rest call inside your method like this (you will need to download the HttpClient from Apache http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.httpcomponents/httpclient/4.4.1)

Comment: DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpGet getRequest = new HttpGet(
"http://mywebservice:port/endPoint/path");
getRequest.addHeader("accept", "application/json");
StringEntity params = new StringEntity("{'username':'yourUsername','password':yourPass'}");
getRequest.setEntity(params);
HttpResponse resp = httpClient.execute(getRequest);
if (resp.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() != 200) {
 throw new RuntimeException("Failed : HTTP error code : " + resp.getStatusLine().getStatusCode());
}
String json = EntityUtils.toString(resp.getEntity(), "UTF-8");
</code></pre>

Comment: You can try something like this:
Message message=new MessageImpl();
Map<String,List> headers=new HashMap<String,List>();
//set your Authorization header as a key of this map, and your user and password inside of the list
message.put(Message.PROTOCOL_HEADERS, yourHeaders);
httpConduit.setHeadersByAuthorizationPolicy(message,url);

This piece of code must override the authorization policy headers. 
More information: 
[link](https://cxf.apache.org/javadoc/latest/org/apache/cxf/transport/http/HTTPConduit.html#setHeadersByAuthorizationPolicy(org.apache.cxf.message.Message,%20java.net.URI))

Comment: I am not able to find public method "setHeadersByAuthorizationPolicy". Could you please tell me which version JAR you have.

Comment: Is the last version of cxf, if you are using another version maybe you can try with this:

httpConduit.getProxyAuthorization().setUserName("username");
httpConduit.getProxyAuthorization().setPassword("password");

This must override the authorization values in the current header. Let see if it will works...

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is that the client you are using to interact with Webservice expecting XML based Soap Messages , while the service is serving JSON as a return media.

Either convert your client to use the JSON format and communicate using that, or alternatively use the XML based endpoint , consult with webservice provider for that.

Comment: If you will see in code then I had specified content type. Like this code bindingProvider.getRequestContext().put(MessageContext.HTTP_REQUEST_HEADERS,Collections.singletonMap("Content-Type", Collections.singletonList("application/xml; type=vnd.iShip.AMP.SOAP")));

Comment: Yes, thats a request that client is pushing but content serving is totally upto the webservice. The server is returning JSON either they are not considering the Content Requested or the Webservice is meant to be like that